# Shoot bows faster by drawing faster

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there any way that I can make bows shoot faster? The attack speed modifier will allow me to make them hit faster, but that doesn't really help. I'm trying to make it so that people with a "Ranger" bow will be able to shoot twice as fast.
*EDIT*
By shoot faster, I don't mean shoot the arrow at a greater speed, I mean draw back the bow to full draw faster.

Answer (score 4):

This actually isn't as farfetched as it may seem. The {NoGravity} tag can be applied to any entity, including arrows, and we can use this to make poorly charged arrows travel farther.

Here's how:

- Firstly, we need to make a "Ranger" team. This will be useful for targeting and executing and such.
  **`/scoreboard teams add Ranger`**
  Make sure that all "Ranger" players are put on this team
- Now we need to turn off Friendly Fire. You will see why in a second **`/scoreboard teams option Ranger friendlyFire false`**

Now on to the actual execution:

- As soon as a bow is fired *from a Ranger*, set the entitydata of the arrow. Execute to all Ranger classes this command on as fast of a clock possible: 
  **`/execute @a[team=Ranger] ~ ~ ~ entitydata @e[type=arrow,r=3] {NoGravity:1}`**
  This will make all arrows that spawn within 3 blocks of a Ranger (which are most likely shot from the Ranger) have no gravity.
- Now that your arrow won't fall, we need to make it go faster! On the very next tick after you turn off gravity, execute this command with a conditional chain command block:
  **`/execute @a[team=Ranger] ~ ~ ~ summon creeper ~ ~ ~ {Team:"Ranger",ignited:1,Fuse:0}`**
  This will summon a creeper that instantly explodes, propelling the arrow. However, it will not hurt the Ranger because it is on the same team as them.

Here's a visual:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can adjust your arrows's speed by a Redstone Repeater. Go over here to find that out :-