# Minecraft: Increase/Decrease Drawback time of bows

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Similar (But unclearly answered) question: [Shoot bows faster](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/264925/shoot-bows-faster)

I would like to create a "Machine Gun" Using commands but I do not know how to implement this using commands. Is there a different way to do it?

Comment: Are you specifically asking within the confines of vanilla? I.e. without mods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot Increase/Decrease drawback time of bows.

Answer (score 1):

If all you would like to do is have a machine gun then I recommend watching this video:

In the case the video goes down here are site references for the commands to do this:

- https://sites.google.com/site/barflandia/one-command/guns
- https://sites.google.com/site/barflandia/one-command/guns/2
- https://sites.google.com/site/barflandia/one-command/guns/resourcepack

**Summary**:

1. Place the fist site command in a command block and activate it.
2. Place the second site command in a command block and activate it.
3. Then you must make a gun crafting table by taking 32 iron and 8 planks and throwing them on the ground together.
4. This should give you an egg, place it and you're ready to go.  The new block is the crafting table.

Comment: At least you tried answering. I do not want some machine crap. All I want is a faster drawback. Thanks nevertheless