# Increasing Arrow Speed

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm playing Minecraft and I want to create a sort of "gun". Nothing special, just a bow with some slight twists.
Decreasing the draw speed is no problem, I already have that figured out.
The one thing I'm struggling with is finding a command to make the arrows travel faster.

Is there a command for that, and if there is, can anyone tell me how to use it?

Comment: The problem is that motion tags in Minecraft are not easy to manipulate. And even with hundreds of command blocks it wouldn't work, because to match the motion tag in the NBT data, you would have to check for every possible value of it, because you can't use > or < for it. So you would have to calculate the velocity yourself by getting the location in two ticks into scoreboards and subtracting them, that takes a few hundred commands per tick already, ... This quickly becomes a giant project and very lag-producing, so I don't think it's worth it. IThink punch ench.makes it fly faster, not sure.

Comment: Mikul Gamour gave an answer that would probably work for this question while trying to answer my question at https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/264925/shoot-bows-faster

Comment: On servers with minigames such as Quakecraft, players use guns to shoot at each other. The technique for doing this is called raycasting, or something similar. I myself haven't looked into this much,  but it could be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the Motion data tag which specifies in how many blocks per second an entity is moving an each axis.
Use this command for 1.14.4:
`/data merge entity (arrow's UUID){Motion:[xmovement, ymovement, zmovement]}`
Replace (arrow's UUID) with appropiate selector for your Arrow and xmovement, ymovement and zmovement with the desired movement values. **This will change the Arrow's speed as well as its damage.**

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use `/effect` for arrows. I already tried it and it makes a change.

You can try `/effect @e[type=arrow] 2 2` in a repeating command block to see the difference.

Comment: this doesnt worka s of 1.13